# почему не работает onclick второй раз

Tags: javascript

```
let pag = document.getElementById("pag");
let pag1 = document.getElementById("pag1");
pag1.onclick = () => {
    pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag now" id="pag1">1</button> <button class="pag" id="pag2">2</button>';
};
pag2.onclick = () => {
    pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag" id="pag1">1</button> <button class="pag now" id="pag2">2</button>';
};
```

при нажатии на любую из них один раз выполняется а потом никакая не работает

Comment: Выложи полный код с HTML

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [почему не работает onclick второй раз на js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1530456/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-onclick-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js)

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляли данные динамически. Поскольку DOM еще не зарегистрирован, обработчик .onclick() не может захватить новый элемент.

Comment: В вопросе про jquery не было сказано. Вы хоть ремарку делайте, а то человек запустит код и словит ошибки