# почему не работает onclick второй раз на js

Tags: javascript

html

```
<div class="pagination" id="pag">
            <button class="pag" id="pag1">1</button>
            <button class="pag now" id="pag2">2</button>
        </div>
```

js

```
let pag = document.getElementById("pag");
let pag1 = document.getElementById("pag1");
let pag2 = document.getElementById("pag2");

pag1.onclick = () => {
    pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag now" id="pag1">1</button> <button class="pag" id="pag2">2</button>';
};
pag2.onclick = () => {
    pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag" id="pag1">1</button> <button class="pag now" id="pag2">2</button>';
};
```

Comment: Знать бы что вообще ты собрался сделать...

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, можно сделать так

```
...
pag1.onclick = (e) => {
    pag2.classList.remove("now");
    e.target.classList.add("now");
}
pag2.onclick = (e) => {
    pag1.classList.remove("now");
    e.target.classList.add("now");
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> почему не работает onclick второй раз

Потому что на новых элементах уже нет обработчиков...

Answer (score 1):

После удаления элементов, все обработчики, связанные с ними, удаляются. Для создания обработчиков для новых элементов(даже с теми же ID), потребуется их заново инициализировать(установить).

Для небольших приложений, предложу вариант:
Создайте функцию обработчик и сразу добавляйте ее в разметку элемента

```js
const pag = document.getElementById("pag");

const click1 = () => {
  console.log('Click1');
  pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag now" id="pag1" onclick="click1()">1</button> <button class="pag" id="pag2" onclick="click2()">2</button>';
}

const click2 = () => {
  console.log('Click2');
  pag.innerHTML = '<button class="pag" id="pag1" onclick="click1()">1</button> <button class="pag now" id="pag2" onclick="click2()">2</button>';
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination" id="pag">
  <button class="pag" id="pag1" onclick="click1()">1</button>
  <button class="pag now" id="pag2" onclick="click2()">2</button>
</div>
```

Либо можно создать универсальные функции, которые будут возвращать нужные кнопки с уже установленными обработчиками

```js
const pag = document.getElementById("pag");
// Обработчик клика
const btnClick = (bType) => {
  pag.innerHTML = '';
  pag.appendChild(createBtn(bType, 1));
  pag.appendChild(createBtn(!bType, 2));
  console.log(bType); // Для демонстрации
}
// Создает кнопку с обработчиком
const createBtn = (btnType, order) => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.classList.add('pag');
  if (!btnType) btn.classList.add('now');
  btn.id = `pag${order}`;
  btn.innerText = order;
  btn.onclick = () => btnClick(order === 1);
  return btn;
}
// Первый рендер кнопок
btnClick(false);
```

```html
<div class="pagination" id="pag">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!!